# Android data backup

Tags: android, backup

I've read the guide about application data backup in Android here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html, but I couldn't understand one thing - how cloud identify what user asks his information. The process is transparent for users, so they don't input any flags for recognitions. For example: user uses application, saves some strings information and then changes mobile device, downloads same application again, installs it and how he gets same information? Maybe there's something I've missed in that android guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup framework is independent of the actual backup service provider, and can use other backup service providers, but the default one is the Google Android Backup service (In the doc that you reference, [The Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#Basics) contains a link to [this page](http://code.google.com/android/backup/index.html)) which will back up the users' data to their Google accounts.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, but couldn't find any proof of that. So, [citation needed] :)

Comment: @Felix Follow the links in my answer. They provide the proof, specifically item 2 in The Basics.

Comment: What I understand from item 2 is that: 1) you can use a different backup service if you want to and 2) you have to register your application, not the user.

Comment: As an app developer, you have to register your app if you wish to back up using the *Google service*, and the *Google service* will authenticate the users via their Google account as and when they backup / restore data from your app. If, as an app developer, you choose to use a different backup service, then this will be completely different, and the user authentication mechanism may be totally different.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, user is most likely identified by his Google Account (Android Market knows your identity, that's why same apps get installed when you wipe your phone or get a new one).

Answer (score 0):

**FYR** - 
On SDK version 23 and up, your app data will be automatically backed up, and restored on app install. Your GCM regid will not work across restores, so you must ensure that it is excluded from the back-up set. Use the attribute android:fullBackupContent to specify an @xml resource which configures which files to backup. More info: https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html